# Using nested columns inside a modal window in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window. Inside this window I have two columns. One columns contain a list of checkboxes. Another column contains a picture and some text. In the right column (with the picture and text) I want to use nested columns (like it is shown in the BS documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) to have the picture and the text be placed on one line. Now, they are stacked. May be the reason is the width of the modal window? Because html code is like in documentation. However it doesn't work.

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

May be it is needed to make the modal window a little wider ?

The code is:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sed at dignissim mauris?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"> Suspendisse in cursus leo, a
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox">Sed ligula elit, lacinia eget pretium
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox"> Phasellus fermentum fringilla orci
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox">  Mauris interdum, sem non
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <img src="Images/testimage.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                                    Ut lobortis arcu sit amet commodo suscipit. Nulla fringilla velit erat,
                                    eget tristique elit ultrices eget. Sed cursus nunc in pretium scelerisque.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I fixed columns issue and now Have a problem with modal window width
[image]

How can I wix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you're using a 12 column grid, so your columns should add up to no more than 12, even when nesting. If you look you're using 'col-lg-4' and 'col-lg-9' which totals 13. Reduce one of these by 1 and it should work.

Comment: Yeah thanx it is my fault. I was just inexact. However I have another problem with the modal window width. How can I fix it? I have updated initial post (added a picture) Thank you.

Comment: You will need to change the css and make it wider

Comment: There is '  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }' css code, but if  I change 600 to 800 for instance, nothing happens.

Comment: Is there any styles on '.modal-content' restricting the width? Do you have a url so we can see?

Comment: Thanks I have resolved the issue. There is the modal-lg class that adds extra 300px to a standard modal window width.